# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Box.V2.dll

Tags: c#

I was getting an exception

An exception of type `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` occurred in Box.V2.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System. Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, Public Key Token=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This exception occurred when i was creating a client using the Box Client class.
the following is the code

```
var config = new BoxConfig(BoxClientId, BoxSecret, new Uri("http://localhost"));

var session = new OAuthSession(access_token, refresh_token, 3600, "bearer");

client = new BoxClient(config, session);
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System. Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0
```

look at your `References` in `Box.V2` project. Seem like you missed the needed lib.

*Sorry for answering, not comment. Cant post comment yet.*